# How to include missing countries to df in r

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

This question is a spin-off from my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67356060/how-to-calculate-moving-average-for-two-years-in-r).

I have a big data frame (900k rows) about mergers and acquisitions (M&As).

The df has four columns: date (when the M&A was completed), target_nation (a company of which country was merged/acquired), acquiror_nation (corporation of which country was the acquiror), and big_corp (whether the acquiror was a big corporation or not, where TRUE means that corporation is big).

Here is a sample of my df:

```
    df <- structure(list(date = c(2000L, 2000L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2003L, 
2003L, 1999L, 2001L, 2002L, 2002L, 2002L), target_nation = c("Uganda", 
"Uganda", "Uganda", "Uganda", "Uganda", "Uganda", "Mozambique", 
"Mozambique", "Mozambique", "Mozambique", "Mozambique", "Mozambique"
), acquiror_nation = c("France", "Germany", "France", "France", 
"Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "France", "France", 
"Germany", "Japan"), big_corp_TF = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

> df

  date target_nation acquiror_nation big_corp_TF
 1: 2000        Uganda          France        TRUE
 2: 2000        Uganda         Germany       FALSE
 3: 2001        Uganda          France        TRUE
 4: 2001        Uganda          France       FALSE
 5: 2001        Uganda         Germany       FALSE
 6: 2003        Uganda         Germany        TRUE
 7: 2003    Mozambique         Germany       FALSE
 8: 1999    Mozambique         Germany       FALSE
 9: 2001    Mozambique          France        TRUE
10: 2002    Mozambique          France       FALSE
11: 2002    Mozambique         Germany        TRUE
12: 2002    Mozambique           Japan        TRUE
```

From these data, I want to create a new column that denotes the **share** of M&As done in specific target nations by big corporations of specific acquiror nations, counting the average for 2 years. (For my actual exercise, I will count the averages for 5 years, but let's keep things simpler here).

There is a group of acquiror nations that I am particularly interested in (for this example, let it be France, Germany, and Japan). I want there to be a column that would denote the abovementioned share for these countries.

@AnilGoyal previously helped me with a code. Here is the code:

```
df_calc <- df %>%
  mutate(d = 1) %>%
  group_by(target_nation) %>%
  complete(date = seq(min(date), max(date), 1), nesting(acquiror_nation),
           fill = list(d = 0, big_corp_TF = FALSE)) %>%
  group_by(date, target_nation) %>%
  mutate(total_MAs = sum(d)) %>%
  group_by(date, target_nation, acquiror_nation) %>%
  summarise(total_MAs = mean(total_MAs),
            total_MAs_bigcorp = sum(big_corp_TF), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  group_by(target_nation, acquiror_nation) %>%
  mutate(share = sum_run(total_MAs_bigcorp, k=2)/sum_run(total_MAs, k=2))
```

This is the output:

```
  date   targ_nat    acq_nat tot_MA big_MA  share
1   1999    Mozambique  France  1   0   0.0000000
2   1999    Mozambique  Germany 1   0   0.0000000
3   1999    Mozambique  Japan   1   0   0.0000000
4   2000    Mozambique  France  0   0   0.0000000
5   2000    Mozambique  Germany 0   0   0.0000000
6   2000    Mozambique  Japan   0   0   0.0000000
7   2001    Mozambique  France  1   1   1.0000000
8   2001    Mozambique  Germany 1   0   0.0000000
9   2001    Mozambique  Japan   1   0   0.0000000
10  2002    Mozambique  France  3   0   0.2500000
11  2002    Mozambique  Germany 3   1   0.2500000
12  2002    Mozambique  Japan   3   1   0.2500000
13  2003    Mozambique  France  1   0   0.0000000
14  2003    Mozambique  Germany 1   0   0.2500000
15  2003    Mozambique  Japan   1   0   0.2500000
16  2000    Uganda     France   2   1   0.5000000
17  2000    Uganda    Germany   2   0   0.0000000
18  2001    Uganda    France    3   1   0.4000000
19  2001    Uganda    Germany   3   0   0.0000000
20  2002    Uganda    France    0   0   0.3333333
21  2002    Uganda    Germany   0   0   0.0000000
22  2003    Uganda    France    1   0   0.0000000
23  2003    Uganda    Germany   1   1   1.0000000
```

All the numbers are as desired. However, I would like there to be the results for Japan's investments in Uganda but cannot succeed in achieving that. **How can I achieve this?** I understand that the reason for there being no results for Japan in Uganda is that Japan has not done any investment in Uganda in any year (as shown in the data sample above); but this lack of investment is a meaningful result for me, and I would like there to be rows for Japan as acquiror nation as well. Just like so (I exclude Mozambique as targ_nat for space reasons):

```
  date   targ_nat    acq_nat tot_MA big_MA  share
16  2000    Uganda     France   2   1   0.5000000
17  2000    Uganda    Germany   2   0   0.0000000
18  2000    Uganda    Japan     2   0   0.0000000
19  2001    Uganda    France    3   1   0.4000000
20  2001    Uganda    Germany   3   0   0.0000000
21  2001    Uganda    Japan     3   0   0.0000000
22  2002    Uganda    France    0   0   0.3333333
22  2002    Uganda    Germany   0   0   0.0000000
23  2002    Uganda    Japan     0   0   0.0000000
24  2003    Uganda    France    1   0   0.0000000
25  2003    Uganda    Germany   1   1   1.0000000
26  2003    Uganda    Japan     1   0   0.0000000
```

Any ideas on how to achieve that? For my actual purposes, I have a group of 13 countries for which I want to see the results as acquiror nations (so not just France, Germany, and Japan). These countries appear in the data set as acquiror nations (but not for all target_nations (!) --- just like in the example of Uganda and Japan here).

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would require `complete`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
out <- df_calc %>% 
   group_by(target_nation, date, total_MAs) %>%
   complete(acquiror_nation = unique(.$acquiror_nation),
   fill = list(total_MAs_bigcorp = 0, share = 0)) %>%
   ungroup
```

-checking the output for 'Uganda'

```
out %>% 
   filter(target_nation == 'Uganda')
# A tibble: 12 x 6
#   target_nation  date total_MAs acquiror_nation total_MAs_bigcorp share
#   <chr>         <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>                       <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 Uganda         2000         2 France                          1 0.5  
# 2 Uganda         2000         2 Germany                         0 0    
# 3 Uganda         2000         2 Japan                           0 0    
# 4 Uganda         2001         3 France                          1 0.4  
# 5 Uganda         2001         3 Germany                         0 0    
# 6 Uganda         2001         3 Japan                           0 0    
# 7 Uganda         2002         0 France                          0 0.333
# 8 Uganda         2002         0 Germany                         0 0    
# 9 Uganda         2002         0 Japan                           0 0    
#10 Uganda         2003         1 France                          0 0    
#11 Uganda         2003         1 Germany                         1 1    
#12 Uganda         2003         1 Japan                           0 0
```

Comment: Works well, thanks. It seems that the 'complete' function deserves more attention. Will look into it.